# How to fill HTML5 input[type=range] on the left side of the thumb with CSS only?

Tags: css, html

Is there a possibility to get the same effect as `::-ms-fill-lower` on Firefox? Without using JS?

I've already found a workaround in order to achieve that effect on webkit based browsers (e.g. Google Chrome) which uses the pseudo elements :before and :after. But it won't work on the Firefox elements. It seems like `::-moz-range-thumb::before` and `::-moz-range-thumb::after` aren't legal operations on Firefox, while Google Chrome supports `::-webkit-slider-thumb::before` and `::-webkit-slider-thumb::after`

Here's a fiddle of the basic outline for the Firefox version:

```css
input[type="range"].slider-track {
  border: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  background: transparent;
}

input[type="range"].slider-track::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background: white;
}

input[type="range"].slider-track::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 380px;">
    <input type="range" class="slider-track" id="mySlider1"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry! I've found the answer 20 minutes after posting this... I was searching for that all day long... 
Here's the answer:

Use the `::-moz-range-progress` element!

Example (works for the snippet)

```
input[type="range"].slider-track::-moz-range-progress {
      background: red;
}
```

Comment: that selector is only working in Firefox, did you find a solution that works also in Chrome and Safari?

Comment: Yes, I found apure CSS solution for webkit based browsers as well, however it's just a workaround.
I'll create a snippet and post a new Question+Answer on Stack Overflow here, since it might be interesting for others as well.
As soon as I have it, I'll send you the link :)

Comment: It was working on Chrome, however Chrome just cut the support on this around a year ago..... Without any replacements - the Chrome Bug Community is still going wild.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are in Vanilla JS - using gradients for Chrome range input:

```
    <div class="chrome">
  <input id="myinput" type="range" value="50" />
</div>

        #myinput {background: linear-gradient(to right, #82CFD0 0%, #82CFD0 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
      border: solid 1px #82CFD0;
      border-radius: 8px;
      height: 7px;
      width: 356px;
      outline: none;
      transition: background 450ms ease-in;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }



     document.getElementById("myinput").oninput = function() {
      this.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, #82CFD0 0%, #82CFD0 '+this.value +'%, #fff ' + this.value + '%, white 100%)'
    };
```

https://codepen.io/saintwycliffe/pen/VBGYXN

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
$('input[type="range"]').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val()/100;
    
    $(this).css('background-image',
                '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, '
                + 'color-stop(' + val + ', #94A14E), '
                + 'color-stop(' + val + ', #C5C5C5)'
                + ')'
                );
});
```

```css
input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperance: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.15, #94A14E),
        color-stop(0.15, #C5C5C5)
    );
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="15">
```

Answer (score 0):

use input change instead of change, so in all browsers the color should fill up while the user is dragging, and not when the user stops dragging

```
$(document).on('input change', '#slider', function() {
    // codes
});
```